# Bash-скрипт сброса пароля root

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

Добрый день!
Нужно написать bash-скрипт сброса пароля root в Mysql. Сделал все по [инструкции](https://billing.adivohost.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=28), но пароль не сбрасывается. Проблема в том, что если вводить команды вручную последовательно - все работает, а если записать в файл и исполнить как скрипт, то нет.

```
#!/bin/bash

/etc/init.d/mysql stop 
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=root & 
mysql -u root -e "use mysql;update user set       
password=PASSWORD('') where User='root';flush privileges;exit"

/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

В чем может быть причина? Помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: Может быть, между

    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=root & 

запускающей что-то в фоне и

    mysql -u root -e ....

которая, наверное, это что-то использует, нужна задержка, которая при вводе команд руками получается автоматически?

Попробуйте вставить

    sleep 30

(если поможет, подберите нужную задержку).

Answer (score 1):

Измени в скрипте

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=root && mysql -u root -e "use mysql;update user set password=PASSWORD('') where User='root';flush privileges;exit"
```

Что изменилось? Вместо одного знака амперсанда используем два, и указываем команды в одну строку. Двойной знак амперсанда означает:
выполняем команду и в случае успешного выполнения выполняем следующую
Следовательно строго после успешного запуска mysqld_safe будет выполнена следующая команда. 
И sleep использовать плохая идея. запуск mysqld_safe может занять времени больше чем sleep, и скрипт опять не сработает